# mobaxterm view in "4 terminals mode"

Tags: mobaxterm

On viewing mobaxterm in "4 terminals mode", I get 3 terminal but the fourth is "home" with setting button.

I tried to make this 4th window a terminal too, but nothing helped.

How can this window be a terminal like the other 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this option within the configuration might work for you:

*Settings > Configuration > Misc > 'Open the following tab at startup: '*

When selecting *Split > 4 terminals mode* afterwards, you should get 4 terminals as desired :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Right-Click on the empty terminal, and select what type of console you want to display (ex. Bash Shell)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the bottom of the home terminal (it might say "1. Home"), then choose the terminal you want to change to.

Right-clicking doesn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34355425)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same session opened twice (or more, obv). Create another session, then you'll be able to change the Home tab for the new one.

Worked out pretty well for me, who moved from Termius which was handling that for me.